# iOS - how to call writeJavascript with parameters in phoneGap / Cordova

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a js method testPN(param), which I need to call from my native app. I am using these lines to achieve that -

```
NSString *jsStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testPN(%@);", custData];
[self writeJavascript:jsStatement];
```

This somehow does not work. If I change to testPN() without any argument and call it like this it works -

```
NSString *jsStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testPN();"];
[self writeJavascript:jsStatement];
```

custData is just a regular non-null NSString* Any idea as to what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the javascript call doesn't occur, or it does actually occur but it is not successful?

Comment: i believe it doesn't even get to the function :-(

Comment: What does writeJavascript look like? Have you tried putting an alert as the first line in the testPN() function to a) check the javescript function is being called, b) check its being called with the arguments you expect? Then if it is c) add an alert at the end of the function and see if its reached, if not then the contents of custData are causing your javascript function to malfunction.

Comment: writeJavascript is a Cordova function in CDVPlugin.h. I tried putting an alert as the first statement and found that it is never being called. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry I'm not intimately familiar with Cordova. But I'm very familiar with the technique PhoneGap uses to call Javascript from Objective-C. So if you get no answers after a while, I presume CDVPlugin.h is open source and available for examination so its internal mechanism could be examined if you could direct me to where to get it. But wait firs see if anybody knows the reason.

Answer (score 1):

> `NSString *jsStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testPN(%@);", custData];`

You have probably forgotten to add quotes in you javascript function's parameters.
`@"testPN(%@);"` should be `@"testPN('%@');".`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this wiki: http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753496/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20iOS

Could that be of any help?

Answer (score 0):

**@Suchi**, if you use **self.webView** like below, it will work properly,

Try this...

NSString *jsStatement = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"testPN(%@);", custData];

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsStatement];
```